# I Have A MERN stack project, and I want to be able to add mutations within an event that is already created by another mutation

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I am creating a Workout Program builder, And I am new to MERN. Below is the resolvers/mutations, createWorkout works perfectly and exactly how I want it too.

```
createWorkout: async (parent, { name, targets, liftComments, excercises, userId }, context) => {
            if
                (userId) {
                const lift = await Lift.create({ name, targets, liftComments, excercises, userId });

                await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: userId },
                    { $push: { lifts: lift._id } },
                )
                return

            }
        },
        addExcercise: async (_, { liftId, name, sets, reps, comments }, { user }) => {
            if (user) {
                const lift = await Lift.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    liftId,
                    { $push: { excercises: { name, sets, reps, comments } } },
                    { new: true }
                );
                return lift;
            }
            throw new AuthenticationError('You need to be logged in!');


        }
```

addExcercise is supposed to go into the array that is within creatWorkout, this is the error I get when trying to run add Excercise in the apollo server

```
{
  "data": {
    "addExcercise": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "AuthenticationError is not a constructor",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addExcercise"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "stacktrace": [
          "TypeError: AuthenticationError is not a constructor",
          }
```

Below is a Screenshot of the DB:
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz1Gp.png)

The error I am getting "AuthenticationError" is being imported at the top of the page from auth.js, bellow is where it is being called from:

```
const { GraphQLError } = require('graphql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const secret = 'superSecret';
const expiration = '1h';

module.exports = {
    AuthenticationError: new GraphQLError('Unable to authenticate the user', 
    {
        extensions: {
            code: 'UNAUTHENTICATED',
        },
    }),
    authMiddleware: function ({ req }) {
        let token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers.authorization;
        console.log(token);
        if (req.headers.authorization) {
            token = token.split('').pop().trim();
        }

        if (!token){
            return req;
        }

        try{
            const { data } = jwt.verify(token, secret, { maxAge: expiration});
            req.user = data;
        } catch {
            console.log('Invalid token');
        }

        return req;
    },
    signToken: function ({ email, username, _id}) {
        const payload = { email, username, _id};
        return jwt.sign({ data:payload }, secret, {expiresIn: expiration});
    },
};
```

My whole goal is to be able to add an excercise through a mutation, and it shows up in the "excercises" array that is shown in the picture and it is empty.

I tried Playing around with the mutations without much luck, and as I am new to this I am runnng out of ideas

Comment: It appears that you are throwing the `AuthenticationError`, this implies that `user` isn't populated.... can you show where you are actually calling this function?

Comment: Where I am calling AuthenticationError?

Comment: no, where you are calling `addExcercise`....  what `user` object is being passed in?

Comment: Oh Okay Sorry, addExcercise is not being called anywhere except the mutation in the typeDefs file, and it is created under the the createWorkout mutation as shown in the question at the top. Does this help? Or do you mean something else? Do you want to see the mutation for it?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the "addExcercise" mutation and it started working

```
addExercise: async (_, { liftId, name, sets, reps, comments }) => {
            return Lift.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: liftId },
                {
                    $addToSet: { excercises: { name, sets, reps, comments } }
                },
                {
                    new: true,
                    runValidators: true,
                }
            );
        },
```